# Use SSD partition on Mac Mini Fusion Drive through Windows Bootcamp

Tags: macos, bootcamp, windows, ssd, fusion-drive

I've been checking through so many questions here, a lot of forum posts, and I can't get a clear answer to what it is I think I want to do.

I bought the fusion drive because well...SSD...I added a bootcamp installation of Windows 10 - which created a partition on the HDD (as far as I can tell based on what I've read so far) - I followed standard Bootcamp procedure.

Anyways, I want to make use of the SSD on my Windows side as well - but I'm not sure how to go about doing this. I don't want to run Windows on the SSD itself, just certain applications like wamp, and my dropbox sync folder. I think it will provide some great performance for wamp and my php development needs.

This is what I've found when looking at Disk Management in Windows:

[image: Disk Management Screenshot]

As can be seen there, Disk 0 is the HDD and Disk 1 is the SSD. Looking above you'll see the Windows partition, (BOOTCAMP (C:).

Also, the SSD, Capacity, 112.68GB, Used, 112.68GB - so...either Mac OS hasn't loaded anything into the SSD as yet, or perhaps Windows just can't read it? I don't know. The Mac Mini is brand new, and I didn't do that much prior to installing Windows.

Would it cause any problems if I partitioned the SSD and formatted one partition as NTFS so that I could make use of it on my Windows side of things as well?

This must sound very stupid - but I'm not very familiar with all of this stuff...

Any advice would be appreciated. Keep in mind, I need to use Mac as well as Windows.

Comment: Golden Rule : Don't mess with either Fusion Drives or Windows partitions outside the Boot Camp setup app itself. Disk Utility will not allow you to do it & Windows will just make a complete & utter mess of the entire drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you'll mess stuff up if you partition it. The fusion drive creates a partition on each drive, which is put together to create the fusion drive. Windows cannot read HFS, so it assumes the disk is empty. Just leave your Windows partition on the HD, and everything should work fine.

Comment: Oh well...I'll just enjoy the fusion drive while I'm using osx then...